# Преимущества и недостатки двух крайностей модульности

Tags: c++, c, архитектура, модульность

Меня довольно долго мучает вопрос, связанный с организацией архитектуры ПО, конкретно игр, конкретно интересует модульность. Я бы хотел понять, как это вообще принято делать, есть ли `кошерные` решения.

Для примера будем рассматривать тривиальную игру, где есть:

- Карта;
- Враги;
- Игрок.

Например, это игра `Pac Man`.

Из возможных градаций подходов организации модульности можно выделить два крайних варианта:

1) Каждый объект - `игрок`, `враг` и `карта` полностью изолированы друг от друга. Игрок ничего не знает о существовании карты и врагов. Враги не знают о существовании карты и игрока. Карта - аналогично.

Каждый объект лишь предоставляет интерфейс для чтения и изменения своего состояния.

Изменением же состояний объектов занимается объект более высокого уровня - игровая механика. Игровая механика получает все нужные ей данные, выполняет просчеты и затем изменяет состояния игрока, карты и врагов.

Отрисовкой, соответственно, занимается модуль отрисовки, который, как и модуль игровой механики, имеет доступ ко всем нужным ресурсам.

Этот вариант ближе к разделению данных и кода.

2) В противоположность прошлому варианту, этот вариант предполагает, что модули имеют циклические зависимости. Модуль предоставляет функции обработки своих объектов и их отрисовки. Причем, функции обработки должны обращаться к врагам и карте. Каждый модуль может менять состояния не только своих объектов, но и состояния объектов из других модулей. Игрок может *убить* врага. Враг может *убить* игрока. Карта может толкнуть врагов или игрока, изменив их вектора скорости.

Этот вариант ближе к самостоятельным объектам.

Первый вариант позволяет легко добавлять новые модули низкого уровня, а так же менять модули игрока, врага и  карты. Однако, из-за того, что вся обработка происходит в модуле игровой механики, кода в одном месте становится так много, что всякие границы ответственности растворяются.

Второй вариант легче спроектировать и сделать. Он более логичен с точки зрения повседневной реальности: вы можете погладить кота, кот может вас укусить, а может и  разорвать обивку дивана. Но такой код невозможно сопровождать или развивать, потому что все происходит везде.

При этом, используемый язык в принципе не имеет значения. Я имел дело с этими двумя крайностями и в `C`, и в `C++`, и в `Java`. И так и не смог понять, как же делать рациональнее.

Comment: Полезно: [entity-component-system паттерн](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system).

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Вот у вас в заголовке написано про модульность, а в вопросе - про объекты. Причем без какой-либо конкретики, даже без намеков на то, чего вы хотите добиться в результате.

Comment: Говоря про объекты, я имею в виду объекты `игрок`, `враги` и `карта`. Говоря про модульность, я хочу понять, как эти объекты, их данные, обработка и отрисовка, должны быть отделены друг от друга.